# How to list all files accessed after running docker?

Tags: linux, docker, filesystems, containers, workflow

I have to deal with some very large vendor support packages for embedded development —- I’ve used docker successfully just as a means of keeping their installs segmented away from the rest of my system and for the sake of environment reproducibility. That works great, but often these installs are monoliths, including a ton of files and functionality I don’t need, especially in a CI environment. And moving giant, slow-to-recreate docker images around is a pain.

So, in the interest of teasing out just the features I need, and porting them to a much smaller image, I’m wondering:

Can I run a docker image, performing some CI-relevant task, and then find all the files that were accessed in the duration the docker image was running?

The plan after that would be to copy all those files into a tarfile or similar, then use that for specialized images in the future. So as an alternative question... is that plan worth pursuit?

Thanks :) -Chloë

Comment: I can monitor files on **my** system. I don't know about yours ;).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will not answer exactly to your question, however it may help.

You can check what is happening in the container by

- checking its logs through the [`docker container logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_logs/) command.
- checking the modification performed in its filesystem through the [`docker diff`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/diff/) command.

Here is an example

```sh
# run a ubuntu container
$ docker run -it --rm --name focal ubuntu:focal

# run a command in the container
$ echo "test" > test.txt

# messages in the logs
$ docker container logs --follow --details focal
# root@aa86b4988bfe:/# echo "test" > test.txt

# checking the differences
$ docker diff focal
# A /test.txt
```